# Upload Progress percent in ajax upload to S3 bucket using the php-sdk with Mulitpart upload

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a video file to S3 bucket using the PHP-SDK and a multipart upload. I managed to make it work via ajax already, but I want to know how to calculate and return the progress? I did a lot of research already but have not found any solutions yet.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide some examples of what you did also :) btw, did you manage to make this work perhaps?

Comment: @trainoasis hey, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `putObject`, which can be converted into MultipartUpload:

```
$client = new S3Client(/* config */);

$result = $client->putObject([
    'Bucket'     => 'bucket-name',
    'Key'        => 'bucket-name/file.ext',
    'SourceFile' => 'local-file.ext',
    'ContentType' => 'application/pdf',
    '@http' => [
        'progress' => function ($downloadTotalSize, $downloadSizeSoFar, $uploadTotalSize, $uploadSizeSoFar) {
            printf(
                "%s of %s downloaded, %s of %s uploaded.\n",
                $downloadSizeSoFar,
                $downloadTotalSize,
                $uploadSizeSoFar,
                $uploadTotalSize
            );
        }
    ]
]);
```

This is explained in the AWS docs - [S3 Config section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#progress). It works by exposing GuzzleHttp's `progress` property-callable, as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34923682/1325575).