# Guzzle 6 progress of download

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I want to download a large file with Guzzle and want to track the progress. I don't know if I have to pass a stream or use the RequestMediator somehow.

- I tried with subscribing to the event curl.callback.progress, but the PSR 7 Request doesn't have an event dispatcher.
- I tried the [on_stats](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats), but the callback is only fired at the end.
- The progress subscriber plugin is deprecated https://github.com/guzzle/progress-subscriber

I'm testing the following code.

```
    $dl = 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso';
    $client = new Client([]);

    $request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('get', $dl);
    $promise = $this->client->sendAsync($request, [
            'sink' => '/tmp/test.bin'
    ]);
    $promise->then(function  (Response $resp) use ( $fs) {
        echo 'Finished';
    }, function  (RequestException $e) {
    });
    $promise->wait();
```

An hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Though, its not mentioned within the documentation, you can use the "progress" request option.

References to it can be found [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/RequestOptions.php).

```
$options = [
    'progress' => function ($dl_total_size, $dl_size_so_far, $ul_total_size, $ul_size_so_far) {
        // do something.
    }
];
```

Comment: In my case, this returns 0 all the time.